# How to force close an application in windows 8 if it is not responding?

Tags: windows-8, task-manager

It sometimes occurs to me that some of the running applications in Windows 8 stop responding. In windows 7 there was an option of going to task manager and right click on a program's icon  and go to its process and then right click on the process and end it. But in Windows 8's task manager only the process shows and then option on the right click is end task. It doesn't end the process if the program is not responding.

Is there any way I can force-close the applications that are not responding (One solution i use is restarting the PC).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean End process tree in Details tab of windown 8

[image]

Comment: Does it force close the not responding applications?

Comment: @BaljeetSingh Yes.

Comment: I could be wrong, but based on my experience, I don't think there is any significant difference in the way Windows 7 and Windows 8 works with regards to the End task process. They both can end **most** applications, but a process can get into a state that neither O/S will do this from the task manager and you have to use taskkill /F or process explorer or something similar. For example, the same problem but on windows 7 has been described at http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-kill-rogue-processes-with-taskkill-in-microsoft-windows/

Comment: Actually, *Details* tab is the good old *Processes* tab in disguise. And *Applications* tab was renamed to *Processes*.

Comment: Some fullscreen games won't allow you to click on the Task Manager window. Is there a shortcut to kill programs directly?

Answer (score 5):

You could do this with a command like

```
taskkill.exe /f /fi “status eq not responding”
```

Or, turn it into a bat file, create a short cut and execute with just a click of a button. [More details](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-kill-unresponsive-programs-without-the-task-manager/)

However, this should be possible via Windows 8 and I would try and find out why it isn't!

Comment: how this works, can you explain the syntax?

Comment: It runs taskkill.exe, and forces a close where the programs status is "status eq not responding"

Comment: Also, only the process tab is visible in the window 8 task manager (no go to process), that is why i asked

Comment: How does it knows which file to close?

Comment: It will look for those programs with that status (so it may close none, close 1 or close many). What program is crashing on you

Comment: Thats great, but i have to wait to confirm it.

Comment: You could also use Taskkill to kill processes by name eg TaskKill /F /IM notepad.exe or by ID, eg TaskKill /F /PID 1234.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), or [Process Hacker 2](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/). They not only work very fine on NT operating systems, and let you end anything you want, they would also show many interesting things. Both applications are very safe (not a malware or virus) and they are way way better than the built-in task manager of Windows.

I highly recommend Process Hacker.